# Firebase notification default image iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've seen that you can set a default image in Android for Firebase push messages like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/smallicon" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Is there a way to do the same in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible to have default image APNS push notification.